# SAP Hana Vora : Failed to create vora table

Tags: vora

I am trying to create a `vora` table using `spark-vora`. but unable to create it getting below error...

```
Caused by: com.sap.hl.catalog.VoraCatalogException$ConnectionTimeoutException: Failure in connecting to the catalog within 2 SECONDS at com.sap.hl.catalog.commands.Utils.handleResult(Utils.java:82) at com.sap.hl.catalog.commands.Utils.getTransaction(Utils.java:26) at com.sap.hl.catalog.commands.Exists.call(Exists.java:24) at com.sap.hl.catalog.commands.Exists.call(Exists.java:10) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Could you please help me resolve this issue. will appreciate for the same.

### Thanks, Akash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message `Failure in connecting to the catalog within 2 SECONDS` indicates that your Vora Catalog is not running. I could reproduce the same error message by shutting down the Vora Catalog in my cluster.

Solution would be to start the Vora Catalog. Make sure that the Vora Dlog is started too as the Vora Catalog is using it.

Comment: Thanks Frank, issue got resolved. Now i am having a different issue. i have created a table as "table001" and stop the instances. Next day i just restart the instances and again tried to create same table "table001". it gives me an error "Table already exist in catalog" but it is not available to me to query it. So could you please tell me how can we clear the vora catalog..????

Comment: Please see [Troubleshooting Blog](http://scn.sap.com/blogs/vora/2015/12/09/sap-hana-vora--troubleshooting) -> How To -> Delete a Vora datasource table from the Vora catalog? Also see [Vora Admin Guide](http://help.sap.com/Download/Multimedia/hana_vora/SAP_HANA_Vora_Installation_Admin_Guide_en.pdf) -> 3.3 Start and Stop SAP HANA Vora Services -> the end of this chapter describes how to reload existing tables into the v2servers after a restart